# Why is my data being appended to my url after editing an item?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, mongodb

I'm building a simple recipe collections app, and I'm running into a really weird scenario where when I edit a recipe item, the new data gets appended to my localhost:3000/ url. For example my original recipe item data was:

"Title: test",
"Ingredients: test",
"Cooking Directions: test"

But then after I edited the data, the new data also appended to my localhost:3000/ url. [data appended to localhost url screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o23Wv.png). My goal is not append this data to my url and stay at localhost:3000. Thanks and any help would be appreciated.

Here is my put request code:

```
updateRecipe = (e) => {
    console.log(this.props.uniqueID);
    const recipe = {
      title: this.state.title,
      ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
      summary: this.state.summary
    }

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/recipes/${this.props.uniqueID}`;
    axios.put(url, recipe)
      .then(res => this.setState({
        recipes: [...this.state.recipes, res.data],
      },
        () => console.log('recipe edited: ', res.data)
      ));
  }
```

```
<form className="form-container" onSubmit={this.updateRecipe}>
            <TextField
              style={inputStyle}
              className="form-input-title"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
              name="title"
              id="standard-basic"
              label="Title"
              value={this.state.title}
            />
            <TextField
              style={inputStyle}
              className="form-input-ingredients"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
              name="ingredients"
              id="standard-basic"
              label="Ingredients"
              value={this.state.ingredients}
            />
            <TextField
              id="outlined-multiline-static"
              label="Directions"
              multiline
              rows={6}
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
              name="summary"
              className="form-input-directions"
              style={inputStyle}
              value={this.state.summary}
            />
            <Fab style={style} className="add-recipe-button" color="primary" aria-label="add" type="submit">
              <AddIcon />
            </Fab>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour if you use onSubmit handler for form.If this is not what you are looking for dont use onSubmit handler on the form instead use onClick handler for the submit button to call for updateRecipe  functionality.Then Url is not modified.